# Does a Braid group/ more generally a finitely generated group have finitely many perfect quotients?

Tags: group-theory, braid-groups

I was wondering about perfect quotients of the Braid groups $ B_n $. Certainly $ B_1=1 $ and $ B_2=\mathbb{Z} $ have finitely many perfect quotients. For $ B_3 $,
$$
1 \to Z(B_3)=\mathbb{Z} \to B_3 \to PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \to 1 
$$
I was wondering about perfect quotients of $ B_3 $, if they have a nice description, and , at even more basic level, if there are finitely many of them.

This led me to the general question:

Does a finitely generated group have finitely many perfect quotients?

Obviously $ \mathbb{Z} $ is a finitely generated group with infinitely many simple quotients $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $ but these are not perfect.

Comment: ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is a free product of cyclic groups of order $2$ and $3$, and it has infinitely many finite simple quotients.

Comment: oh oops ya all the $ PSL(2,p) $ are finite simple I guess that was obvious

Comment: The group $PSL(2,\Bbb Z)$ is *not* perfect.

Comment: I see I guess since it is a free product of $ C_2 $ and $ C_3 $ then the abelianization is just $ C_2 \times C_3 \cong C_6 $. I'll edit to remove the claim that it is perfect

Comment: Your question is now answered for $B_3$, but I don't know whether $B_n$ for $n>3$ has infinitely many perfect quotients (or any at all). These groups are residually finite, so they have plenty of finite quotients.

Comment: In fact $B_4$ seems to have lots of simple quotients, but not $B_5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's very interesting, could you say more about the many simple quotients of $ B_4 $?

Comment: @DerekHolt Does $ B_3 $ surject onto $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ or is it just $ PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $

Comment: The answer is yes, but please don't ask new questions as comments to exiting questions.

Comment: @DerekHolt Good point! I've now asked this as a separate question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723980/what-are-the-two-dimensional-representations-of-b-3-does-b-3-surject-on

Comment: @DerekHolt what makes you say that $ B_5 $ does not seem to have a lot of simple quotients? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449421/perfect-quotients-of-braid-groups seems to suggest that every $ PSp(2m,p) $ is a quotient of $ B_5 $ for the appropriate value of $ m $. On an unrelated note, any quotient of $ B_3 $ is a quotient of $ B_4 $ since $ B_3 $ itself is a quotient of $ B_4 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No a finitely generated group does not always have finitely many perfect quotients.

In fact, every Braid group has an unbounded number of finite perfect quotients.

Ian Agol notes here

https://mathoverflow.net/a/449481/387190

that the paper *A’Campo, Norbert*, [**Tresses, monodromie et le groupe symplectique**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02566275), Comment. Math. Helv. 54, 318-327 (1979). [ZBL0441.32004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0441.32004) [MR0535062](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0535062)

shows that every braid group $ B_n $ has quotient $ Sp(m,\mathbb{Z}) $ for some $ m $. And thus, for that $ m $, every finite perfect group $ Sp(m,p) $ for $ p $ prime is a quotient of $ B_n $. Thus every $ B_n $ has infinitely many finite perfect quotients.