# What are the two dimensional representations of $ B_3 $? Does $ B_3 $ surject onto $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $ B_3 $ be the braid group on three strands. What are the two dimensional irreps of $ B_3 $? In particular show that $ B_3 $ surjects onto  $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $. The way to do this would be using the presentation of $ B_3 $ and some standard generators for  $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $. But it isn't immediately clear to me which generators to pick.

Context: $ B_3/Z(B_3) \cong PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ so it seems reasonable that $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ is also a quotient. I asked about this here [Does a finitely generated group have finitely many perfect quotients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721822/does-a-finitely-generated-group-have-finitely-many-perfect-quotients?noredirect=1#comment10009622_4721822) but Derek Holt suggested that it would be better to ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$B_3 = \langle a,b \mid aba=bab \rangle \cong \langle x,y \mid x^2=y^3 \rangle$ (where $x=aba$ and $y=ab$).

${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z}) \cong \langle x,y \mid x^2=y^3, x^4=1 \rangle$ (see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group:SL(2,Z))).